# Как правильно собрать javafx 11 приложение?

Tags: javafx, tornadofx

Как правильно собрать javafx 11 приложение, чтобы оно нормально запусталось у пользователя на компе без танцев с бубном(под windows 7,10)?

Или что пользователю нужно установить еще кроме java 11 ?
Очень запутался в данном вопросе, ответ так и не нашел. C 8-ой джавой всё было проще, установил и всё работает.

Пользовался данным руководством https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#modular , использую gradle.

```
plugins {
//    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.50'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '5.1.0'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.12.0'
}

group 'ru.test'
version '0.1'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
mainClassName = 'ru.test.start.MyAppKt'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/konrad-kaminski/maven' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect'

//    implementation group: 'org.jsoup', name: 'jsoup', version: '1.12.1'
    implementation group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'
    implementation 'no.tornado:tornadofx:1.7.19'
    implementation group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx', name: 'kotlinx-coroutines-javafx', version: '1.3.0-M2'
    implementation group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.3'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.10.0.pr1'

    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20'
    implementation 'org.brunocvcunha.inutils4j:inutils4j:0.6'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.8'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.8'

    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.9'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.9'
//    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.5.9'
    implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1'
    implementation 'org.bytedeco:javacv:1.3.1'

    implementation "org.openjfx:javafx-controls:$javafx.version:win"
    implementation "org.openjfx:javafx-controls:$javafx.version:linux"
    implementation "org.openjfx:javafx-controls:$javafx.version:mac"

    implementation "org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:$javafx.version:win"
    implementation "org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:$javafx.version:linux"
    implementation "org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:$javafx.version:mac"

    implementation "org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:$javafx.version:win"
    implementation "org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:$javafx.version:linux"
    implementation "org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:$javafx.version:mac"
}

javafx {
    version = "11"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml', 'javafx.graphics' ]
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

shadowJar{
    archiveName = "TestProg-${version}.6.${extension}"
//    manifest {
//        attributes 'Main-Class': 'ru.test.TestHereKt'
//    }
}

jlink {
    launcher {
        name = 'ru.test.start.MyAppKt'
    }
}

jar {
    archiveName = "TestProg-${version}.6.${extension}"
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'ru.test.start.MyAppKt'
    }
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

Comment: А в чем проблема, также просто поставить `Java 11`?

Comment: @And в java 11 нет javafx. А простому пользователю всё это устанавливать и настраивать очень трудно.

Comment: Кто-то не читает документации и `oracle` - это теперь отдельный модуль. ну так возьмите и встройте, в чем проблема?

Comment: @And , вот я и спрашиваю как правильно это сделать с помощью gradle. подскажите, данная инфа будет полезна многим, не только мне.

Comment: зависимость подключите в `dependencies`. Если не мобильное приложение, скачайте модуль и внедрите в вашу либу.

Comment: @And да в том и дело, что я уже всё что только можно повнедрял. Всякими способами, которые описаны на сайте jfx. Но под windows 10 c чистым openjdk(jre)-11 не запускается. Приложил файл gradle

Answer (score 0):

1. Установил jdk-12.0.1 и настроил переменную окружения JAVA_HOME в эту папку.
2. В соответствии с руководством https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx
   скачал  JavaFX Windows SDK v.12.0.1 (openjfx-12.0.1_windows-x64_bin-sdk.zip) с сайта https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/  и распаковал его в соответствующую папку.
3. Проверил по инструкции сборку немодульного javafx-приложения HelloFX (Gradle project) для NetBeans 11.1 и IntelliJ IDEA Community 2019.2. Проблем не возникло, за исключением одного нюанса: для IDEA требуется подправить файл MainApp.java (указать полный путь к файлам ресурсов:

   ```
   Parent root = XMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/org/openjfx/scene.fxml"));

   scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/org/openjfx/styles.css").toExternalForm());
   ```

   В противном случае (если путь не указан) IDEA выдает сообщение об ошибке. Для NetBeans этот момент не является критичным.
4. Для сборки модульного javafx-приложения дополнительно требуется скачать JavaFX Windows jmods (openjfx-12.0.1_windows-x64_bin-jmods.zip) и распаковать в локальную папку. Дальше всё по инструкции.

Comment: ну я примерно так и пробовал, не получается что-то. Где-то недопонимаю.

Answer (score 0):

Для корректной работы JavaFX 11 версии необходимо:

1. Скачать JavaFX 11 версии с [официального сайта.](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/)

2. Распаковать архив в любую папку (я сделал это в папку с *IDE*)
3. В *IDE* нажимаем *File -> Project Structure -> Libraries*
4. Нажимаем *New Project Library*
5. Вставляем путь к папке *lib* из архива
6. Активируем эту библиотеку на Ваш проэкт и всё будет работать.

*P.S. Делал всё на Intellij IDEA, возможно у Вас будут немного иные пути добавления. Но смысл точно такой же будет. У меня заработало!*

Answer (score 0):

Я бы рекомендовал JPackageScriptFX - удобный инструмент для публикации приложения. Включает в себя скрипт с настройками для Jlink и jpackage.
[Скрипт и документация](https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX).
В документации не написано, но не забудьте про библиотеки Jmods для javafx (я скопировал их все в папку jdk/jmods