# IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2 x64. Ошибка при попытке запуска кода на Java

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-idea

Создал новый проект на базе JavaFX. Запускаю автоматически сгенерированный код, ничего не менял. По логике ожидаю запуска "пустого окна" , но получаю следующую ошибку: Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.base not found

Искал по запросу, всё что нашёл - ни привело ни к чему. JavaFX подключил, VMOptions прописаны. (Скрины по ссылкам).

https://yadi.sk/i/mdUZ_w3ZmisiJQ
https://yadi.sk/i/3-M1JnJvtTU9Ug

Comment: Возможно, дубликат вопроса:https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1023862/Как-правильно-собрать-javafx-11-приложение

Comment: Начните новый проект по инструкции здесь: openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#introduction, создайте далее по пунктам своё приложение HelloWorld. Вы не указали версии продуктов, это важно. Предварительно убедитесь что версии достаточно свежие, например: jdk12, javafx-sdk-13, IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.

Comment: JavaFX выше восьмерки поставляется отдельно.